# error while pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, theano

I tried to do tutorials on https://github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-rnnlm. when I did `pip install -r requirements.txt` I came to error messages like following:

```
(venv)  ~/PycharmProjects/rnn-tutorial-rnnlm $ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting appnope==0.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached appnope-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2.tar.gz
Collecting certifi==2015.9.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached certifi-2015.9.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator==4.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached decorator-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting funcsigs==0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached funcsigs-0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting functools32==3.2.3.post2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached functools32-3.2.3-2.zip
Collecting gnureadline==6.3.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached gnureadline-6.3.3.tar.gz
Collecting ipykernel==4.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached ipykernel-4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython==4.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached ipython-4.0.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython-genutils==0.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached ipython_genutils-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipywidgets==4.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Using cached ipywidgets-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2==2.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Using cached Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jsonschema==2.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Using cached jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Using cached jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-client==4.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-console==4.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Using cached jupyter_console-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-core==4.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe==0.23 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Using cached MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Using cached matplotlib-1.4.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.4.3]
                    python: yes [2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)  [GCC
                            5.4.0 20160609]]
                  platform: yes [linux2]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.12.1]
                       six: yes [using six version 1.10.0]
                  dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                            axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                      pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                            it after matplotlib.]
                   tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                            WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                 pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.2.0]
                     pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: no  [The C/C++ header for libpng (png.h) could not
                            be found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                            found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                            matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install may attempt
                            to install it after matplotlib. / mock is required
                            to run the matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install
                            may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]
            toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                            matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install may attempt
                            to install it after matplotlib. / mock is required
                            to run the matplotlib test suite.  pip/easy_install
                            may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
                    pyside: no  [PySide not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: no  [TKAgg requires Tkinter.]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: yes [version 9.18]
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: yes [version 0.41.0]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SBYScG/matplotlib/
```

why did these things happen? any help would be very much appreciated! thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have the `python-dev` package installed on your system?

Comment: Which Linux distribution and version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            freetype: no [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h) could not be found. You may need to install the development package.] 
            png: no [The C/C++ header for libpng (png.h) could not be found. You may need to install the development package.]
```

This quite clearly states that you have to install freetype2 and libpng header files.